# Ping command in ioredis-Node JS

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

Is there any way to check weather redis is available or terminated due to some issues before I am setting or getting a key ? How can I achieve that?

I am using `ioredis` module.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 var Redis = require('ioredis');
 var redis = new Redis();


 var test = redis.ping(function (err, result) {
     console.log(result);
 });
```

The result should be the word `PONG` if no paramters are passed and Redis is working.

[PONG](http://redis.io/commands/ping): This command is often used to test if a connection is still alive, or to measure latency.

Comment: I am not getting response back if the redis is unavailable, I am getting PONG after redis got up, Is there any way to get immediate response for PING command.

Comment: ioredis will try to reconnect to the Redis server when it's unavailable. Disalbe `retryStrategy` and you'll get the response immediately.